# How do I pass flask-script options to children

Tags: python, flask-script

I have the following three modules (based on Miguel Grinberg's excellent book):

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from config import config

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

`manage.py`

```
import os
from app import create_app
from app.import_file import Import_File_CLI
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell, Command

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('import_file', Import_File_CLI())

manager.add_option('-v', dest='verbosity', help='how verbose output should be - the more vs, the more verbose', action='count', required = False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

`import_file.py`

```
from flask.ext.script import Command, Option
from flask import current_app
import logging

class Import_File_CLI(Command):
    "Imports files from the command line"

    option_list = (
        Option(help="file to import", dest="filename"),
    )

    def run(self, filename, verbosity=0):

        if verbosity == 1:
            log_level = logging.WARNING
        elif verbosity == 2:
            log_level = logging.INFO
        elif verbosity > 2:
            log_level = logging.DEBUG
        else:
            log_level = None
```

I'm going to be doing a lot of file manipulation, and I want to be able to do some testing/debugging from the command line, so there are going to be a number of _CLI modules for different things.  I want to be able to control the verbosity of the output I get, so I have the verbosity option defined.  What I can't figure out is how to actually pass that option into the Import_File_CLI class.  I know I can add an option to the option_list, but then I end up having to add that to every _CLI class I create, when I really want it to be a global option.  So how do I access an option I set in the main manager in a subclass?

The documentation sort of has an example of this, but it's in the same module, not a subclassed one.  I could pass the option into the factory function, and then set an app-wide default, but that seems less than optimal as well, since I most of the time don't need to set it.  Do I need to create a _CLI submanager, possibly?